# How to get a number of documents starting by a certain document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

Let's say, in mongo db, I have a collection like this:

```
{_id: "A", Value: "1"}
{_id: "B", Value: "2"}
{_id: "C", Value: "3"}
{_id: "D", Value: "4"}
{_id: "E", Value: "5"}
{_id: "F", Value: "6"}
{_id: "G", Value: "7"}
{_id: "H", Value: "8"}
{_id: "I", Value: "9"}
```

and I have a method named M (ID, LIMIT), which gets last LIMIT records starting with document ID in reverse order.

How do I implement method M?

**Ex 1:**

```
M(F, 4) returns
{_id: "F", Value: "6"}
{_id: "E", Value: "5"}
{_id: "D", Value: "4"}
{_id: "C", Value: "3"}
```

**Ex 2:**

```
M(H, 2) returns
{_id: "H", Value: "8"}
{_id: "G", Value: "7"}
```

**Ex 3:**

```
M(G, 6) returns
{_id: "G", Value: "7"}
{_id: "F", Value: "6"}
{_id: "E", Value: "5"}
{_id: "D", Value: "4"}
{_id: "C", Value: "3"}
{_id: "B", Value: "2"}
```

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing.  The letters seem to be ID values but you're also showing them as keys in the docs.  It would help if you could update your example to be valid JSON.

Comment: Updated notation as you offered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the results by `_id` while also sorting descending by `_id`:

```cs
var cursor = test.FindAs<BsonDocument>(Query.LTE("_id", ID));
cursor.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("_id"));
cursor.SetLimit(LIMIT);
```